# javascript getElementById for listStyle

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but the bullets of the list wont change, please help.

This is the html

```
<div id="recetas_prepa">
<p class="recetas_preparacion">Preparación</p>
 <ul id="recetas_preparacion_lista">
    <li>Quitar aomo de 1 o 2 cm, salpimentándolas a continuación.
    </li>
    <li>En picado y la Mostaza Para CUando, removiéndolo todo.
    </li>
    <li>A de un poco de arroz blanco, unos champiñones o patatas hervidas.
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
#recetas_prepa{
    width:480px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:lime;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#recetas_preparacion_lista li{
    color:#333333;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:8px 15px 0px 12px;
    list-style:decimal inside none;
}
```

and this is my JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv()
    {
        var imgPath = new String();
        imgPath = document.getElementById("recetas_info").style.display;

        if(imgPath == "inline" || imgPath == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("recetas_info").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("recetas_ingre").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.clear = "none";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.width = "350px";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.height = "90px";
            document.getElementById("recetas_preparacion_lista").style.listStyle = "disc inside none";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("recetas_info").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("recetas_ingre").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.clear = "both";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.width = "480px";
            document.getElementById("recetas_prepa").style.height = "auto";
        }
    }
</script>
```

There are some other stuff there but the the last of the if, i mean this line:

```
document.getElementById("recetas_preparacion_lista").style.listStyle = "disc inside none";
```

is the one that is not working, I have no idea why, it just wont change.

Comment: Are u sure that you are calling the function changeDiv() anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your css to

```
#recetas_preparacion_lista li{
    color:#333333;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:8px 15px 0px 12px;
}
```

and add

```
#recetas_preparacion_lista{
     list-style:decimal inside none;
}
```

You code will work now, since the css is not overridden by then fact that your javascript addresses the `ul` element while the CSS addresses the `li` elements.

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SHCYw/